# "resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found." in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, aapt

I have a react-native project and it works ok yesterday for android, But error happens today when i run `react-native run-android`. Before I run it on android today ,nothing is changed,only open it in `AndroidStudio`. The Error as following:

> .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/d1dde4fd0fa50f7f7336597688c557a9/res/values/value
>   s.xml:252:5-69: AAPT: error: resource
>   android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/d1dde4fd0fa50f7f7336597688c557a9/res/values/value
>   s.xml:252:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

And the main config as the following:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8"

gradle plugin:com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
```

I spent a lot of time to resolved it, but failed.

Most resolutions are that upgrade android to AndroidX,But i cannot,because my prohect have many dependencies,and some of them are not support AndroidX.

So I want to know **why need `android:attr/ttcIndex`** when i run it.And how to fix it and donot upgapde android version and keep `compileSdkVersion 27`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This helped me

in the top of file android/gradle.properties

```
googlePlayServicesVersion=12.0.1
```

And create new index.android.bundle

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Podolyak, It works, only add `googlePlayServicesVersion=12.0.1` into gradle.properties.Could you explain why need to add `googlePlayServicesVersion=12.0.1`?

Comment: Or give me some links which can explain it.

Comment: This link is explain it
[link](https://medium.com/@yathousen/the-day-google-decided-to-shake-the-react-native-community-4ba5cdd33388)